# SQL Server Table With Multiple Entry Types

Tags: sql-server

I'm not that experienced with SQL server but I need to come up with a solution to the following problem.

I'm creating a database that holds cars for sale. Cars are purchased via a handful of ways (contracts), here are 2 examples of the pricing fields needed:

I've left out unnecessary fields for the sake of clarity.

- Type: Personal Contract Hire
- Fields: InitalPayment, MonthlyPayment
- Type: Personal Contract Purchase
- Fields: InitialPayment, MonthlyPayment, GFMVPayment

The differences are subtle.

The question is, would it be better to create a table for each type along with some kind of header table or create a single table with a few extra unused fields? Or something else?

I know the purists will hate me for even raising the question of redundancy but the solution has to be practical too and I'm worried about overcomplicating something that needn't be.

I'm using Entity Framework as my ORM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would also depend on how you'd want to query them. And also how many records for the two types would there be? Would it be very skewed or about 50-50? Are the number of rows going to be "a lot" (tens of millions +) ?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu My thoughts exactly. I don't want something that is difficult to use through the ORM. I would expect there to be thousands of rows but not 10's of thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never designed a database, but I work with them everyday at my job. The databases I encounter were designed by professionals with years of experience in IT, and many of our tables face the same issue you are describing here. Every single time the answer is create a single table with a few extra unused fields. I realize this may just be the preference of the IT team and that this is not the only way to do it, but as someone who writes dozens of business-analytics queries a day, I can confidently say that this design is very natural and easy to use.

You're probably going to run into this problem again in the future. You may even create another type that requires a 4th field. Imagine if every time that happened, you just added another table. Your database would quickly become hard to manage, and anyone else using it would need to memorize which three or four tables give access to pretty much the same data, with only subtle differences. That's not very user-friendly.

Overall, I suggest creating a single table with some unused fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tend to agree. I've been looking at inheritance patterns (several tables linked together) and to be honest it seems like it will be a ball ache to query, even something simple like retrieving a customers orders (1 customer, several orders, different types in different tables).The beauty is that the pricing fields are unlikely to change much (if at all) once if I get it right and I can probably get away with a single method in linq to sort the data out.